Where clause doesn't work with aggregate without group by Clickhouse
I'm trying to count sum and count without group by with three different conditions and add written flag to distinguish them from each other. Then I'm trying to get the only one record with certain flag. But the result query from cte doesn't filter as I expect. It works the same as if I add filter by flag_purchase to where clause in cte.
DDL and inserts for table:
    CREATE TABLE t15
    (
        `winner_price_wo_vat` Nullable(Decimal(38, 2)),
        `prc_lot` Nullable(String),
        `business_code` String,
        `business_unit` Nullable(String),
        `is_finished` Nullable(String),
    )
    ENGINE = MergeTree
    ORDER BY business_code
    SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
    INSERT INTO t15 (winner_price_wo_vat,prc_lot,business_code,business_unit,is_finished) VALUES
         (100.00,'1','1','1','1'),
         (100.00,'2','1','2','1'),
         (200.00,'3','2','1','1'),
         (250.00,'4','2','1','1'),
         (300.00,'5','3','1','1');


My query:
    with cte as (
    select 
        'competitive' as flag_purchase
        , SUM(winner_price_wo_vat) as sum_wo
        , COUNT(prc_lot) as cnt
    from t15
    where 
        1=1
        and business_code = '1'
        and is_finished = '1'
    union all 
    select 
        'open' as flag_purchase
        , SUM(winner_price_wo_vat) as sum_wo
        , COUNT(prc_lot) as cnt
    from t15
    where 
        1=1
        and business_code = '2' and business_unit = '2'
        and is_finished = '1'
    union all 
    select 
        'closed' as flag_purchase
        , SUM(winner_price_wo_vat) as sum_wo
        , COUNT(prc_lot) as cn
    from t15
    where 
        1=1
        and business_code = '3' and business_unit = '1'
        and is_finished = '1'
    )
    select 
        flag_purchase
        , sum_wo
        , cnt
    from cte 
    where 
        1=1
        and flag_purchase = 'closed'

Output:
    flag_purchase|sum_wo|cnt|
    -------------+------+---+
    competitive  |      |  0|
    open         |      |  0|
    closed       |300.00|  1|

If I'm adding group by in cte then it works as expected - output contains only one record where flag_purchase = 'closed'.
Why does Clickhouse work like that and can I solve this problem only with group by?

Can you create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? (sample CREATE TABLE + data)

updated, added DDL and inserts for table

Looks like a bug to me. I managed to create a reduced test case: with cte as (   select 'a' as foo, count() from numbers(2)   union all   select 'b' as foo, count() from numbers(2) ) select * from cte where foo = 'a'; This returns rows with foo = 'b'.

Just to confirm, I ran the same query in DuckDB (replacing numbers with generate_series) and it returns only 1 row.

It looks like it is a bug - I created the issue: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/65630.

As an alternative consider using this query:
SELECT
    multiIf((business_code = '1') AND (business_unit IS NULL), 'competitive',
            (business_code = '2') AND (business_unit = '2'), 'open',
            (business_code = '3') AND (business_unit = '1'), 'closed', '?') AS flag_purchase,
    business_code,
    business_unit,
    SUM(winner_price_wo_vat) AS sum_wo,
    COUNT(prc_lot) AS cnt
FROM t15
PREWHERE (business_code IN ('1', '2', '3')) AND (is_finished IN ('1'))
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS (
        (business_code),
        (business_code, business_unit))
HAVING flag_purchase = 'closed'

/*
   ┌─flag_purchase─┬─business_code─┬─business_unit─┬─sum_wo─┬─cnt─┐
1. │ closed        │ 3             │ 1             │    300 │   1 │
   └───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴────────┴─────┘
*/


Some recommendations:

avoid using Nullable types (see Clickhouse string field disk usage: null vs empty)
consider using LowCardinality(String) instead of String type.

